# Need to fix the formatting issue in ansible - File from remote server

Tags: ansible

I am writing ansible code to update a DB table and output of the DB update is copied to a text file. 
Fetching the contents of the file from remote server and displaying in ansible output. Having issue in formatting the table contents

Please find below the code.

```
  win_shell: 'invoke-sqlcmd –ServerInstance {{ DBServer }} -Database {{ DBname }} -Query "{{ query2 }}" -ErrorAction Stop -QueryTimeout 65535 | Out-File -FilePath {{ log_path }}'

- name:
  win_shell: cat "{{ log_path }}"
  register: log_output

- name: Current DB vaules - Before deployment
  debug:
    msg: "{{log_output.stdout}}"
```

The Ansible output is displayed as
 `"msg": "\r\nCALCULATION THREAD_COUNT\r\n---------------------- -----------------------\r\n                     4                      96\r\n\r\n\r\n"`

Need output exactly as it is in log file

```
CALCULATION            THREAD_COUNT
---------------------- -----------------------
                     4                      96
```

Query used
`SELECT CALCULATION,THREAD_COUNT FROM CALCULATOR_DESC`

Please suggest to produce a proper formatting when I run ansible code

Answer (score 0):

You cannot control that, formatting is done by various callback plugins and using `debug` module is not as in doing a `print()` from your code. It is more like doing `logging.info(msg)`.